# How to pass variable between methods in a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am just trying to pass a variable between 1 method to another in the same Laravel controller. I have spent hours trying to figure this out and have had no luck. I am sure it is very simple. There are similar answers here elsewhere, but I can't make them work, so want to make it really simple so I can understand it.

In the below code, I just want to add output $variable (in this case, the number 1).

Eg, let's say i have the following methods in a controller.

```
public function index()
{
$variable = 1;
}

public function show()
{
dd($variable);
}
```

I just want the show function to dd output 1 as initialised in the index function. Can anyone lend me a hand. As I said, I am sure it's easy, just can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not call function index inside function show

Comment: Please use getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Type 1** : You can pass with **defined variable**.

```
protected $variable;
public function index() {
    $this->variable= 1;
}

public function show() {
    echo $this->variable;
}
```

**Type 2** : Another way to call **method from one method to another is**

```
public function index() {
    $variable= 1;
    $this->show($variable);
}

public function show($id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

**Type 3** : You can use **session** as well.

```
public function index() {
    $variable= 1;
    session()->set('variable', $variable);
}

public function show() {
    $variable = session()->get('variable');
    dd($variable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, when I add this, I am getting null returned in the show method.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a variable in the controller class which should have the scope within that class.

```
private $variable;
```

Then in any function you can use this variable with `$this` keyword

```
$this->variable = 1;
```

**Update**

You probably need a [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to initialize the variable.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->variable = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, when I add this, I am getting null returned in the show method.

Comment: Are you initializing your `$variable` somewhere?

Comment: I'm initializing it in the public function per my example. I think I see, perhaps the issue is that I am not calling my index method, and that is why it is not being initialized. I will have a play with that, thankyou for your suggestions all.

Comment: Then you need to call `index` function inside the constructor as well if it is modifying the variable value

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:
Define the variable outside the functions:

```
protected $variable;
public function index()
{
$this->variable = 1;
}

public function show()
{
dd($this->variable);
}
```

Case 2: 
You set the variable is parameter in the second method, and then call your method from the first method you're working with

```
public function index()
{
$variable = 1;
$this->show($variable);
}

public function show($variable)
{
dd($variable);
}
```

Comment: if you want to call one method to another method it should be used with `$this->show($variable)` $this is necessary.

Comment: Case 1 just returned null.In case 2, this looks promising, but I am already passing parameters to it, when I add a third, it complains that I am only passing exactly 2 paramaters. this is my current show method ... public function show(Ticket $ticket)
    {...

Answer (score 1):

way you wrote code,
isn't proper

```
public function index()
{
$variable = 1;
}

public function show()
{
dd($variable);
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected-in-php/

You need to clear with Access specifiers.
define before use in function or use in construct with $this.
Or call second function from first function with arrgument.